# Troubleshoot python audio chapterize script

Tags: python-3.x

I don't quite understand the error when running the beginning of this script (from https://github.com/Geremia/chapterize):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Concatenate audio files and add chapter markers.
import glob, os, tqdm, sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Usage example: " + sys.argv[0] + " concatenated.mp4 '*.mp3'")
    exit()

cattedAudio = sys.argv[1]
inputAudio = sys.argv[2]

inputAudioFiles=glob.glob(inputAudio)
inputAudioFiles.sort()

starttimes=[]
time = 0 #cummulative start time (nanoseconds)
for i in tqdm.tqdm(inputAudioFiles):
    time += float(os.popen('sox "' + i + '" -n stat |& head -2 | tail -1 | grep -o "[0-9.]\+"').read().strip())*1e9
    starttimes.append([i, str(int(time))])
```

Error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `sox "001.mp3" -n stat |& head -2 | tail -1 | grep -o "[0-9.]\+"'
  0%|                                                       | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chapterize1a.py", line 19, in <module>
    time += float(os.popen('sox "' + i + '" -n stat |& head -2 | tail -1 | grep -o "[0-9.]\+"').read().strip())*1e9
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Each mp3 file should be read, creating timestamps.

Comment: you are getting this error because there is space `''`  and you are trying to convert it to `float`

Comment: Thanks, I get that. But why is there a space as output? And what is causing the syntax error?

Answer (score -1):

I solved all issues by creating a python script that can take in pure unchapterized audio files and create one chapterized audiobook. Chapter metadata is taken from the title of the corresponding file.

This forced me to learn Python, so I'm grateful.

FYI for anyone coming across this:

I'll write about it on my blog to explain: https://verityj.github.io

Script: https://gist.github.com/verityj/5eec7bcacfe60c3fb418f28a4688a61b

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).